# How to check if a integer is sum of given integers?

Tags: c#, algorithm, integer-division

Lets say I have a integer `result` and an array of integers, lets say `[a,b,c]` (not a fixed length). I need to detect if `result=a*i +b*j + c*k`, with `i,j,k>=0`.

I prefer a solution in C/C# if it is possible.

PS The problem is from a reservation system, a trip can be sold if its durations is a combination of given durations.

Thanks!

Ex:  if we have a=3, b=7
  than  rezult 20 = 3*2 + 7*2
        result 9 = 3*3 + 7*0

Comment: A good question, but a clarification for what the preferred outcome is. Assuming a,b,c are the durations, while i,j,k are the quantity of each duration, do you prefer the fewest count of durations (i+j+k is minimal) or the fewer count of longer durations (prioritize lower value of a,b,c)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467907/ (complex but rather optimal)

Comment: I just want to know if a combination exists!

Comment: Are your durations fixed? Some combinations of parameters can be solved trivially with a 'greedy' algorithm, and a few - powers - are even simpler than that.

Answer (score 6):

This is the [Frobenius Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem) which is in general NP-Hard.

For small instances, reasonably fast algorithms are known, though.

The paper here: http://www.combinatorics.org/Volume_12/PDF/v12i1r27.pdf seems to describe previous algorithms (which includes an application of Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm!) plus it gives a new algorithm which is apparently faster than the previous ones.

In any case, for the case when there are only 2 numbers, a and b such that gcd(a,b) = 1, finding i, j >= 0 such that a*i + b*j = M is easy to solve.

It is also known that any number greater than (a-1)(b-1) *can* be represented in the form a*i + b*j, with i >=0 and j>= 0. The Frobenius number is defined to be the largest number that cannot be represented in that form, and exists when n >= 2 and gcd(a,b,c...) = 1.

So in your case, if the numbers involved are small enough, you could sort the array, find the 'smallest' two a and b such that gcd(a,b) = 1 and see if M >(a-1)(b-1), which can be solved just using a and b.

if M <= (a-1)(b-1), and a and b are small enough, you might just be able to brute force it out.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem statement is too vague to be sure - what are the possible values of i, j, k... if the input vector is not a fixed length?

It sounds to me as if your issue is a variation on the [knapsack problem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)